# Is it possible to tell if an HTTP request originates from a "save link as" action?

Tags: http, browser, http-headers

Is there any way for a server to determine if a particular HTTP request was initiated by right-clicking and selecting *"save link as..."* from the context menu in chrome (or its equivalent in other browsers).

For example, some header that is sent in one scenario but not in the others.

My initial hunch is the answer is no, but it would be interesting to experiment with this type of behavior.

---

### Why would anyone want to know this?

As a simplified example, assume we have view with a list of files where each of them links to another view that essentially pretty-prints the file contents, along with some metadata and offers the ability to download them.

Sometimes a user just wants to save a few of them and has to go back-and-forth between the item view and the list.

If she tried to use the context menu for that as it is at the moment, she would get the HTML source of the single-file view, of course, and that is normally not the desired behavior (at least in our case).

I have the obvious option of adding a "download" control for each item in the list, or even a custom context menu, but if I could detect such scenario on the  server, I could deliver the file itself instead of rendering the page and the user could *right-click > save-link-as* and get the file contents, and the list view won't have to be cluttered with the additional controls.

---

I wish this type of functionality existed on GitHub (saving files right from the file list) or Moodle (a course management platform), so I am hoping to to save some frustration where I have control.

Answer (score 1):

There is no real difference in the request being sent to the server, except maybe for some headers added (Firefox):

```
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

But you can't rely on that.

**Here's what you can do**:

Suppose you have a file like this:

```
http://www.yoursite.com/test.csv
```

This url should **always** return the **raw file**. For example, that url could be in an email, or on a forum somewhere.

To display a page when the user clicks that link on your site, you could catch the `OnClick event` (and do some extra checks maybe), and add a parameter to the url with JavaScript:

```
http://www.yoursite.com/test.csv?display=html
```

Your server could then return the html page you want (and in case JavaScript is turned off in the browser, no harm will be done, the file will be returned as is).

> I wish this type of functionality existed on GitHub (saving files right from the file list) or Moodle (a course management platform), so I am hoping to to save some frustration where I have control.

This can be very annoying indeed. Good to see someone's paying attention to those details.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Sorry for taking so long to respond. I like the direction, but I need to do some more research before drawing any conclusion. For now, I am looking into the implementation of `mouseup`, `mousedown` and `click` events across browsers. On right-click and menu selection, it seems like `mousedown` is the last event fired and on left click (full click, w/o dragging away), up+down+click are fired in succession. `click` may very well be the appropriate event to handle it, but I will think it through, in order to find/eliminate edge cases.

Comment: @MasterAM - Yes, I think checking `click` would be best. Single click -> html, ctrl- or shift-click -> html. That leaves: dragging: could be to another tab or browser-window, but could also be to Explorer (which would save a link) - both might link to the html maybe - you could check on StartDrag or something like that. Right-click/context menu: user could select 'save as' as well as 'open in new tab'.. - here you might return the file url, or you would need to check which menu-item was selected (for every browser..) - depends on how far you want to go.

Comment: @MasterAM -  The easy way: click or drag -> html, otherwise: csv.